# Minimum ALTER Permissions to scale Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions, azure-sql-database

I'm using the following query to scale up/down Azure SQL server programatically:

> ALTER DATABASE [DB] MODIFY(EDITION='Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='S3')

And I used this [StackExchange Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102593) to give the DB user enough permissions to run the query:

> GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE:: [DB] TO [username]

However I don't want to open up this user to have more database permissions than necessary.

Is there a way to only give ALTER access to modify the SERVICE_OBJECTIVE and not have any other heightened permissions?

Comment: move the code into a stored procedure and only grant the user right to call the proc in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate the `ALTER DATABASE` command in a stored procedure and sign it with a certificate that confers `ALTER DATABASE` permissions. This will permit minimally privileged users, with only execute permissions on the procs, to scale the database up/down even without `ALTER DATABASE` permission.

Example T-SQL script below.  TL;DR, see [Packaging Permissions in Stored Procedures](https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html).

```
--create certificate and cert user with necessary permission
CREATE CERTIFICATE AlterDatabaseCert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'p%FD$4bb925DGvbd24^9587y'  
   WITH SUBJECT = 'For Alter Database User';   
GO  

CREATE USER AlterDatabaseUser
    FROM CERTIFICATE AlterDatabaseCert;
GO

GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE::[DB] TO AlterDatabaseUser;
GO

--create and sign stored procedures
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_ScaleUpDatabase
AS
ALTER DATABASE [DB]
    MODIFY(EDITION='Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='S12');
GO

ADD SIGNATURE to dbo.usp_ScaleUpDatabase
    BY CERTIFICATE AlterDatabaseCert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'p%FD$4bb925DGvbd24^9587y';
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.usp_ScaleDownDatabase
AS
ALTER DATABASE [DB] 
    MODIFY(EDITION='Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE='S3');
GO

ADD SIGNATURE to dbo.usp_ScaleDownDatabase
    BY CERTIFICATE AlterDatabaseCert
    WITH PASSWORD = 'p%FD$4bb925DGvbd24^9587y';
GO

--grant execute permissions to minimally privileged users/roles
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.usp_ScaleDownDatabase TO [username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.usp_ScaleUpDatabase TO [username];
GO
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is the certificate just another security precaution?  Presumably you get the same benefit of isolating the permissions even without the certificate?

Comment: Also how do you run the SP as AlterDatabaseUser?  Or is that what the cert helps to identify?

Comment: @Marcus, no "run as" is needed as signing adds a security token at run time to the execution context. See the article link in my answer for more details.

Comment: Without the signing, the proc will fail if the user doesn't have `ALTER` permissions because ownership chaining does not apply with `ALTER DATABASE` statements.

Comment: Tested that and it works beautifully.  Nice work :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only give ALTER access to modify the SERVICE_OBJECTIVE and not have any other heightened permissions?

As siggemannen suggested when you want to give a minimum permission to user on database create a stored procedure and give only execute permission on that stored procedure.

In your case you need to grant two permissions to user:

1. As you want to alter database you need to grant Alter permission on database.
2. create stored procedure and give execute permissions for that respective stored procedure only.

First create a stored procedure to modify database.

```sql
create procedure scaleupdown(@Edition VARCHAR(50), @Service_Objective VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = CONCAT('ALTER DATABASE database1 MODIFY(EDITION = ''',@Edition,''', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ''',@Service_Objective,''')')
EXEC(@SQL)
End
```

Then grant permissions to user

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.scaleupdown TO demouser1;
GRANT ALTER ON DATABASE:: database1 TO demouser1;
```

The stored procedure where user has permission to execute other than that it will throw an error:

[image]

Comment: This solution still gives ALTER permissions to demouser1 though?  Can you give the ALTER permissions to the SP and not demouser1?

Comment: AFAIK we perform the operations on data base using user so we have to grant permission to him. we cant grant grant alter permission to SP.